# Adding switch case

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I want to add switch case to not allow the user to write string when entering temperature or when there is nothing to delete it says "there is nothing to delete, go back to menu".

```
List<string> Temp = new List<string>();

while (true)
{
    string val;
    Console.WriteLine("[L] ägg till temp-mätning: ");
    Console.WriteLine("[S] kriv ut alla temperaturer och medeltemperatur");
    Console.WriteLine("[T] ag bort temp-mätning");
    Console.WriteLine("[A] vsluta");
    Console.Write("Selection: ");

    val = Console.ReadLine();

    if (val == "l" || val == "L")
    {

        Console.WriteLine("add temperature : ");
        Temp.Add(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Clear();
    }

    else if(val == "s" || val == "S") 
    {
        int index = 1;
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine($"Your temperatures are: ");
        Temp.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"{index++} - {x}"));
    }
    else if (val == "t" || val == "T")
    {
        Console.Write($"Which temp do you want to delete [index from 1 to {Temp.Count}]: ");
        int deleteIndex = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) - 1;
        Temp.RemoveAt(deleteIndex);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("incorrect input: ");
        Console.Clear();
        break;

    }
```

Comment: The code is not C++.  I recommend you adjust your language tags.  In C++, console output uses `std::cout`, while C# uses `Console.Write`.

Comment: In C++, you could use the `std::toupper` or `std::tolower` to convert the `val` to upper case or lower case before comparing.  This eliminates half of the comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

**Please check C# reference websites or books before asking questions.**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/

Here is the code you wanted, hope this helps you:

```
List<string> Temp = new List<string>();

while (true)
{
menu:
    string val = string.Empty;
    Console.WriteLine("[L] ägg till temp-mätning: ");
    Console.WriteLine("[S] kriv ut alla temperaturer och medeltemperatur");
    Console.WriteLine("[T] ag bort temp-mätning");
    Console.WriteLine("[A] vsluta");
    Console.Write("Selection: ");

    val = Console.ReadLine();

    switch (val.ToLower())
    {
        case "l":
        addTemperature:
            Console.WriteLine("add temperature : ");
            string temperatureInput = Console.ReadLine();
            int temperatureToAddToList;
            try
            {
                temperatureToAddToList = Convert.ToInt32(temperatureInput); //This line trys to convert string variables to integer variables. If string variable includes any character, it will throw an exception.
            }
            catch (Exception error) //If an exception was thrown, this code block gets activated, which will give out the message you asked for.
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number instead of a string!");
                goto addTemperature;
            }
            Temp.Add(temperatureInput.Trim());
            Console.Clear();
            break;
        case "s":
            int index = 1;
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine($"Your temperatures are: ");
            Temp.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"{index++} - {x}"));
            break;
        case "t":
            if (Temp.Count == 0)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("There is nothing to delete, go back to menu.");
                goto menu;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write($"Which temp do you want to delete [index from 1 to {Temp.Count}]: ");
                int deleteIndex = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) - 1;
                Temp.RemoveAt(deleteIndex);
                break;
            }
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("incorrect input: ");
            Console.Clear();
            break;
    }
```

I have revised and updated my code example to better solve your problem.

Comment: OP asked to find a way to allow taking temps without errors when a string is entered (instead of int). If its string, pop an error and ask again. How does your solution resolves that?

Comment: @Jawad Sorry, I have edited my comment to solve what OP asked for. If possible, could you please check this one?

Comment: @FeritYiğitBALABAN tnx for ur answer. When i run the program it says "The name tamp doesnt exist in the current context"

Comment: @KhanAli Hmm, that's weird. I ran the code on my machine, it was working correctly.  Could you have copied something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To control use input you can *extract methods*, e.g.

```
 private static int ReadInteger(string title) {
   while (true) {
     if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title))
       Console.WriteLine(title);

     if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int result))
       return result;

     Console.WriteLine("Incorrect syntax, please, try again.");
   }
 }
```

then you can put

```
 val = Console
   .ReadLine()
   .Trim()      // Let's be nice and tolerate leading / trailing spaces, e.g. " L "
   .ToUpper();

 val = val.Substring(0, Math.Max(1, val.Length));

 switch (val) {
   case "L":
     // We read valid integer, turn it to string and out to Temp
     Temp.Add(ReadInteger("add temperature : ").ToString());
     Console.Clear();

     break;
   case "T":
     int deleteIndex = ReadInteger(
       "$"Which temp do you want to delete [index from 1 to {Temp.Count}]: ");

     if (deleteIndex >= 0 && deleteIndex < Temp.Count)
       Temp.RemoveAt(deleteIndex);
     else
       Console.WriteLine("Index out of range");

     break;

  ...   
 }
```